# How to check the condition the array contains the element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, if-statement

Code:

```js
monthArray = ["jan 2009", ..., "dec 2009"];
```

The jsonFile contains:

```js
[
    {
        "month": "Aug 2012",
        "no_Of_Commits": 1
    },
    {
        "month": "Jun 2012",
        "no_Of_Commits": 1
    },
    {
        "month": "Apr 2012",
        "no_Of_Commits": 6
    }
]
```

```js
function populate(jsonFile) {
    tempJson = jsonFile;

    for (var i = 0; i < monthArray.length; i++)
    {       
        if (monthArray.contains(tempJson[i]["month"]))       // condition Not working suggest anything else
        {
            console.log("yes");
            tempJson[i]["no_Of_Commits"] = tempJson[i]["no_Of_Commits"];
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("NO"); 
            jsonFile[i]["no_Of_Commits"] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `contains` with [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
if ( monthArray.indexOf( tempJson[i]["month"] ) !== -1 ) {...
```

and as you're iterating over one array, and getting values from another array, you better make sure both arrays have the same number of indices etc.